# find every possible list in a list of lists

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I have a tuple containing of two lists of lists called temp:

```
temp = 
(
 [
  [
   [
    [
     [
      [
       [1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
       ],
       [0.0, 0.0, 3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
      ],
     [
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 4.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
     ]
    ],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
   ],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 7.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
  ],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 8.0, 0.0, 0.0]
 ],
 [
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 9.0, 0.0],
      [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0]
 ]
)
```

I want to find every possible list structure in this data called temp, and make a numpy matrix out of those lists for example:

first row of matrix=[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

second row of matrix=[0.0, 2.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]

tenth row of matrix=[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 10.0]

Comment: The structure of your list is very weird. The first element is in a list in a list in a list,...

Comment: You may want to read [help/on-topic], [ask] and [mcve], and re-word your question accordingly.

Comment: You need to post your work, otherwise it looks like "do this for me." If you search for "python list flatten" you may get some ideas. I got a working solution with some recursion and isinstance(x, list) ... minus the numpy part which I didn't think was relevant.